# Postmark mailing working only on production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postmark

I have three environments and postmark mailing is just working on `production`. I checked the api keys that I created and nothing. I even tried to use the same api key from production and it doesn't work on staging.

```
Rails v. 5.0.1
```

gemfile:

```
gem 'postmark' (v.1.14.0)

gem 'postmark-rails' (v. 0.18.0)
```

**production.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
  config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_token => ENV["POSTMARK_API_KEY"] }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "www.mywebsite.com" }
```

**development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
  config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_token => ENV["POSTMARK_API_KEY"] }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

**staging.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
  config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_token => ENV["POSTMARK_API_KEY"] }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "myapp.herokuapp.com" }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the ENV with the actual API key as a string (for development only)?

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer and I tried and the environment is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to send email on using the method `deliver_now` instead of `deliver_later` and worked. I guess the problem is with `redis gem` configuration that I have to figure it out.